# Installing EF june 2011 CTP..where is the compile tab?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4

The installations procedure 
[link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/announcing-the-microsoft-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp.aspx) tells me to do changes in the compile tab .
why is it that i do not see the compile tab ?
[image: screenshot]![enter image description here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't read the installation procedure correctly. Compile tab is only for retargeting VB.NET project but you are using C# project where retargeting is done in Application tab.

Comment: so am i correct in understanding that if use the msi installer for june 2011 CTP i need to un-install the nuget package i already had in the project ?

Comment: CTP is not distributed as NuGet - it is separate msi and assemblies are registered to GAC. It also has separate installation of new designer tools which will replace your current designer (= don't make this on your production / work machine).